# NPM Install is not able to install all modules and it hangs halfway

Tags: node.js, npm

I am to running `npm install` and it stops halfway and stays there forever.
This is the line where it hangs.

```
fetchMetadata: sill resolveWithNewModule express-robots@0.1.6 checking installable status
```

Comment: Try using `yarn` instead. If that doesn't work as well, then something is either wrong with the package or your package file.

Could you also add your `package.json` to the question?

Comment: sure, I will try that out. Thanks Chris

Answer (score 0):

I kept running into this on a project and I noticed it would hang and then flash a new line and then go back to the previous hanging message. Running npm `install --verbose` did not give me any more info so I did a screen recording and stopped it on that line.

It was asking for my repo ssh password. Once I entered that, the install continued and finished without any issue.